# ERROR 3680 (HY000): Failed to create schema directory 'wwww' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)

Tags: mysql, errors

I'm trying to create a database using MySQL but getting an error message as follows:

```
mysql> create database XXX
    -> ;
ERROR 3680 (HY000): failed to create schema directory 'XXX' (errno: 2 - No such
file or directory)
```

Comment: This may help you: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/error-1006-hy000-can-t-create-database